# Program in C that shows that the square of a positif number is equal to the sum of the first odd numbers

Tags: c

this what I coded but it is not working. When I enter a number the program gives me a wrong result. Please can anyone show me where the problem is

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    int N;
    int S;
    int i;
    printf("donner un entier >0");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    S=0;
    
    for (i=1;i<=N;i++) {
        
        if (N%i==1){
            S=S+i;
            
    }
    
    
    }
    printf("le carré de l'entier est égal a %d",S);
}
```

Comment: By definition, 4 unrelated language tags makes this too broad.  As well 'not working' is a feeble an insufficient problem description.

Comment: Python? Java? C#? or C ? You must first decide which programming language!

Comment: I am using C for this program

Comment: Then please don't spam-tag inappropriate unrelated programming languages

Answer (score 2):

The test inside the loop should be:

```
if (i%2==1) {
    S += i;
}
```

This is true if the current loop index is odd.  It can be shortened to just:

```
if (i%2) {
    S += i;
}
```

which has the same effect.

A more efficient approach is to change the loop increment to skip over the even numbers.  That way no test is needed inside the loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= N; i += 2) {
    S += i;
}
```